# DFSR speed Server 2008r2

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, dfs-r, file-replication-services

**So, here’s the simple setup:**

2 sites, each with their own file server (server standard 2008r2 fully updated)

100MB WAN link at each site

1.7TB shared drive

Replication schedule 64Mbps at night and 32Mbps during the day

200GB staging folder, 2GB Conflict/Deleted folder

No folder quotas

No Antivirus

No Firewall between the two machines or domain controllers

**No errors in the log**

For a long time after initial replication, everything was running great and fast.  Then there was a power outage at site 1 that outlasted the battery backups and the two sites got out of sync.  Once we brought the server back up it wasn’t replicating and giving an error 1315 (complaining about the vector size).  After much digging and coming up empty, I decided the easiest way to get rid of the error would be to recreate the replication group.  This worked! After a few hours the folder at site 2 went from “uninitialized” to “awaiting initial replication”.  However, several hours later, the replication is still going at about 1500 Bytes per second, occasionally jumping to 3000Bps.  With the available link speed, I would imagine that it should be much, much, much faster than that.

At this point I would expect to see something in the error log telling me what the holdup is, but it’s not showing any errors.   Currently the staging folder is around 73GB and well under the high water mark.

If it stays at the current 24Kbps this is going to take forever to get back into sync.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `1.` You say that after the initial replication things have been fine, but what kind of transfer rates were you seeing during the initial replication? `2.` You state that the servers each have a 100Mbps WAN connection, but what about the connection in between the servers? Do you have a 100Mbps point to point connection between them or is the data traversing the internet via a VPN connection?

Comment: I'm not sure what the speeds were like prior to the outage... But I do know that it was pretty quick and no one complained.  You are correct.  The data is traveling across the internet via VPN, but when I tested with a simple copy/paste of a 400MB file between them, I was getting an average speed of 1.41MB/sec.  If I could get DFS-R to transfer at that rate, instead of the 24Kbps it's giving me, I'd be a happy admin.